# Are you allowed to withdraw from 401k for no reason if leaving the company?

Tags: united-states, 401k, withdrawal

I've searched the internets extensively but I am finding it surprisingly difficult to find a straightforward answer to a very simple question.

Assuming I leave the company, can I just withdraw all the money in my 401k account, including the company's match, minus the 10% penalty & taxes? Or do I need a valid "hardship" reason and/or wait until I'm 59 1/2?

Comment: You do know you can roll your 401k into a new employer's program, and/or roll it over into an IRA without any penalties? Also, you can withdraw up to $10,000 penalty free (you still pay taxes) if you use it on a house down payment (not always the smartest move, but if you really want to use it, that's a fairly good use).

Comment: @SnakeDoc: yes, the issue is if I have to leave the US, for various reasons it might be more useful to just take it out.

Comment: Well, you can certainly have an IRA and be outside the US (and IRA is not tied to any company, and you can move it around between IRA providers if you decide you don't like one for any reason). There are very few really good reasons to raid your tax sheltered retirement accounts (and they were designed to be as such).

Comment: @SnakeDoc that depends on the laws of the home country though. Just as the US completely ignores tax shelter laws for pensions/retirement savings in other countries, other countries could not care less about the US tax sheltering the IRAs. In some places having an account out of the country may be illegal, in which case the OP may just be forced to withdraw.

Comment: @littleadv OP is in Stanford California

Comment: @SnakeDoc I think the OP disagrees with you on that. See his reply to your question.

Comment: @littleadv The rules regulating tax advantaged accounts don't just vanish the moment you set foot outside the US.

Comment: @SnakeDoc as I said, while the US regulations don't vanish - other country's regulations appear. The fact that the account has preferential tax treatment in the US may have no meaning elsewhere.

Comment: @littleadv He'll have to follow US regulation on his US based 401(k)... even if he's physically in another country. Even if he renounces citizenship, he'll be bound by the same regulations and terms agreed to when the account was opened. It's a moot point really.

Comment: @littleadv You seem to think people can run to Mexico and withdraw their US-based tax sheltered accounts penalty free... that's absurdly false. If OP has dual citizenship, they'll likely pay taxes in both countries, but they cannot escape early withdraw penalties (which is what this question is about!!!) simply by leaving the US.

Comment: @SnakeDoc where did I say anything about "penalty free"? What I said was that sometimes people may be better off paying the penalty and closing the account.

Comment: As someone who did not save enough for retirement when young and stupid, I impore you not to scuttle your retirement like that.  Even if you are moving to another country, the US typically has treaties that allow you to move it to that country's 401K equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

As long as you're willing to pay the taxes and the penalties, once you're no longer employed you're allowed to do whatever you want. You can always do an "direct roll-over" (See IRC Sec. [401(a)(31)(A)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/401) which mandates this) and then withdraw from another qualified account, thus creating a withdrawal, if they refuse to just mail you a check (Why would they care? Don't know).

The match may have some vesting restrictions, though. Your own contributions - are yours to do with whatever you feel like.

---

That said, just pointing out the obvious - it's a very bad idea. Unless you expect to die before you're 60 and don't want to leave a dime to your heirs, you would probably be better off leaving it in a tax-sheltered account. If the custodian is bad - just roll over elsewhere, there's tons of excellent IRA providers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42516/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-are-you-allowed-to-withdraw-from-401k-for-no-r). The system alerts mods when comments continue to this extent.

Comment: In the chat noted in the comment by @JoeTaxpayer, there's some convincing evidence that this answer is completely wrong. Unfortunately the chat will not persist, but see the answer by Chris below.

Comment: @Brick Chris makes a lot of noise, but I have yet to have seen something authoritative. I did research my position, since you've all been so confusing, and found the statute that explicitly requires a *direct* roll-over to be made available. As such, direct/indirect is a mere technicality - you can directly rollover to an IRA and then do a withdrawal, the net effect is the same. I'm referencing it in my -1 comment to Chris. BTW: It took me 10 minutes to find it, once I started looking.

Comment: I encourage people to follow the link to the law that @littleadv has cited and read it carefully. It certainly does not support his position, even if ultimately he is correct for other reasons.

Comment: @Brick why do you conclude pp 31A is not enough to support his answer?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer The text at (31)(a) starts: "A trust shall not constitute a qualified trust under this section unless the plan of which such trust is a part provides that if the distributee of any **eligible rollover distribution** ..." [Emphasis added]. The question is what constitutes an eligible rollover distribution, and this paragraph does not answer that. *If you have an eligible rollover* then this paragraph says the sponsor has to provide a mechanism to make it a direct rollover. It does not say (here) which rollovers are eligible.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer If you go down to (31)(D), it defers the definition of "eligible rollover distribution" to another section. If you go there, IIRC, it further defers it yet elsewhere. I followed that rabbit hole for a couple of hops and never saw anything supporting this answer. I do allow that it might be there somewhere, but I looked for a while and could not find it.

Comment: Section 402 describes **taxability** of amounts in a qualified trust, not the conditions a trust is required satisfy to make it "qualified". It's pointing out direct rollovers as a specific mechanism that must be offered because direct rollovers are not subject to mandatory 20% withholding while Indirect rollovers are.

Comment: @littleadv You're answer is still wrong because you can't do "whatever you want after you're no longer employed" and because you can't "always do 'a' direct rollover"

Comment: @Chris you keep saying that, yet I've seen no proof. All the resources, including the IRS and FINRA that I quoted, say you're wrong.

Comment: @litteladv See the comments in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Most plans yes, but it depends on your specific plan's provisions.

You want to get a Summary Plan Description for your specific plan. Speak with HR (assuming you have one, or whoever is in charge at your company) and request a Summary Plan Description (they are legally required to provide you with one if you ask, although there may be a small cost to you for printing). It will tell you in there when distributions may be made following severance of employment as it pertains to your specific plan.

An excerpt from the doc submitted to the IRS for plan approval -

[image]

option g would be the choice that's available, and participant should watch out for.

This is the response (a small excerpt, the full doc ran 2 pages and had private information) -

[image]

It confirms the full document (the plan itself) was approved.

Comment: -1. You're wrong, I'm sorry. See IRC Sec. 401(a)(31)(A) and 401(a)(31)(C) which are directly related to what I said in my answer.

Comment: For those who have commented on the lack of a reference saying this is ok, I'd point out that the default (at least in USA) is that anything not forbidden is allowed. (You similarly won't find a law that says you're *allowed* to change your cloths at noon. There may be some specific places where it's not allowed, and you could find those prohibitions written somewhere, but otherwise the government is out of it.)

Comment: Not sure if @Chris will move his documents from chat to here, but he's provided there an IRS letter stating that the plan documents used by his company comply with the law and an excerpt from the relevant plan document. We cannot independently verify that he didn't make the whole thing up, of course, but it seems legit. He left some identifying numbers on the IRS letter, for example, that allow his company to be identified as an 401(k) service provider with an IRS-approved plan (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/ppa_listdc.pdf). Of course, it's fine to be skeptical and think he faked that too.

Comment: @littleadv Dude, I'm not wrong. I can't fake that: a rollover is a distribution, that retirement plans (DB, DC, MP, ESOP) are all "qualified trusts" governed under the rules in Section 401, and that Section 401 allows a qualified trust to restrict payment of benefits (which means distributions) even after a separation from service.

Comment: @Chris - can you confirm that (a) the box in question is in fact used for the standard 401(k) plan that we are used to, and not a defined benefit plan or other pension, and (b) whether you've administered any plan that checked that box?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I assume you mean the documents I posted in the chat. Yes, I can confirm that that document is used for a qualified (IRS opinion letter) 401(k) Profit Sharing Plan like you are used to seeing. I have not worked directly with a plan that has restricted distributions past termination, however, several of my colleagues have.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://benefitslink.com/boards/index.php/topic/44064-delayed-distribution-of-employer-money/#entry190111) to BenefitsLink.com, which is a well-respected industry forum, where someone has almost the same problem. The answers there also point to Section 401(a)(14) as being the rule on timing of distributions. Here's [another question](http://benefitslink.com/boards/index.php/topic/34618-401k-withdrawal-limit/#entry143232) with answers that back up my answer & [also this](http://benefitslink.com/boards/index.php/topic/20319-profit-sharing-retirement-plan-distribution/#entry75849)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I posted 3 links to BenefitsLink.com, a website for benefits professionals. The answers there support my position.

Comment: Look at the very last answer in link #2 and Katherine's answer (2nd from bottom) in link #3.

Comment: The recent links you gave seem to confirm your position, and I've given the answer an upvote. So, accepting this as fact, we are left to always need to warn people to check the Summary Plan Description for their post employment options, warning that even at say, 62, withdrawal or transfer may not be an option.

Comment: With your permission, I'd like to move the evidence (from chat) to your answer. I have the images and can redact any numbers that lead to your company. That, and the links, offer the Black Swan I was requesting.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yes, that's fine, as long as all identifying information has been redacted.