# Contribution limit to 401k after changing job and rollover old 401k to traditional IRA

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira

Let's say I contributed $8,000 to my 401(k) while working at company X in 2016. Later I quit company X. I am now working at company Y. I'm thinking of rolling over the 401(k) at company X to traditional IRA. My question is, what's my contribution limit to 401(k) at company Y for 2016?  Is it $10,000 or $18,000? In other words, does the rollover "reset" the contribution to 401(k)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your deposits, if under age 50, are limited to the $18,000. The rollover doesn't change this. Company match is separate from the $18,000.

As we discussed in [a recent question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67229/are-you-allowed-to-withdraw-from-401k-for-no-reason-if-leaving-the-company), verify the former employer permits this.